# Integrate $\int\frac{xe^{2x}}{(1+2x)^2}dx$

Tags: calculus

Integrate $\int\frac{xe^{2x}}{(1+2x)^2}dx$

$u= 1+2x$

$du= 2 dx$

Now I saw a solution where a person took $xe^{2x}$ all together and used it as "du" but I did not understand how they were allowed to do that.

If "u" must consist of the first function of this mnemonic: L-I-A-T-E

L: Logarithmic Function

I: Inverse Function

A: Algebraic Function

T: Trigonometric Function

E: Exponential Function

Keep in mind I am only allowed to use Integration by Parts.

Comment: i really doubt that this integral is avaiable to the techniques u mention

Comment: Integration by parts works. Choose $\frac{1}{(1+2x)^2}$ as $du$

Comment: @ imranfat why are you allowed to differentiate $xe^{2x}$?Isn't one an algebraic function, x and one and exponential function?

Comment: @Sunny Use the product rule to differentiate $xe^{2x}$.

Comment: @ Dr. MV why are you allowed to differentiate $xe^{2x}$?Isn't one an algebraic function, x and one and exponential function $e^{2x}$?

Comment: Why is that relevant?

Comment: Because I want to know the rules. This does not follow L.I.A.T.E  I was under the assumption one could not lump  functions together arbitrarily. Can you make me aware?

Comment: @tired I'm not offended.  But others might be offended by your choice of word.  ;-)) -Mark

Comment: @Dr. MV i'm in the final stage of my PhD thesis, so my mood is not the best sometimes. So apologies if my wording is a little bit "primitive" at the moment, i didn't mean something bad to anyone... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If one is restricted here as suggested in the OP,  then we proceed as follows.

First, let $u=e^{2x}$ and $v=\frac{1}{4(2x+1)}+\frac14 \log(2x+1)$.  So, $du=2e^{2x}$ and therefore we have

$$\begin{align}
\int \frac{xe^{2x}}{(1+2x)^2}\,dx&=\frac{e^{2x}}{4(2x+1)}+\frac14 e^{2x}\log(2x+1)\\\\
&-\int \frac{e^{2x}}{2(2x+1)}\,dx-\frac12 \int e^{2x}\log(2x+1)\,dx \tag 1
\end{align}$$

Now, we integrate by part the first integral on the right-hand side if $(1)$ by setting $u=e^{2x}$ and $v=\frac14 \log(2x+1)$.  So, $du=2e^{2x}\,dx$ and therefore we have

$$\begin{align}
\int \frac{xe^{2x}}{(1+2x)^2}\,dx&=\frac{e^{2x}}{4(2x+1)}+\frac14 e^{2x}\log(2x+1)\\\\
&-\left(\frac14 e^{2x}\log(2x+1)-\frac12\int e^{2x}\log(2x+1)\,dx\right)-\frac12 \int e^{2x}\log(2x+1)\,dx\\\\
&=\frac{e^{2x}}{4(2x+1)}+C
\end{align}$$

---

**NOTE:**

In using integration by parts, We are free to choose the $u$ and the $v$ functions.  So, $u=xe^{2x}$ is perfectly acceptable and actually facilitates analysis.  Let's see how to proceed.

If we let $u=xe^{2x}$, then $v=\frac{-1}{2(2x+1)}$.  Proceeding, we have $du=(2x+1)e^{2x}\,dx$.  Therefore,

$$\begin{align}
\int \frac{xe^{2x}}{(1+2x)^2}\,dx&=\frac{xe^{2x}}{2(2x+1)}-\int \frac{-1}{2(2x+1)}(2x+1)e^{2x}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac{xe^{2x}}{2x+1}+\frac{e^{2x}}{4}+C\\\\
&=\frac{e^{2x}}{4(2x+1)}+C
\end{align}$$

Comment: dv is $\frac{-1}{2(2x+1)}$? If so how are you calculating v? "v" would be $\frac{1}{(1+2x)^2}$

Comment: Sunny.  Are you talking about the second development - the one under "NOTE?" If so, $v=\frac{-1}{2(2x+1)}$, not $dv$.  $dv=\frac{1}{(2x+1)^2}\,dx$

Comment: @ Dr. MV Maybe it will be easier for me to follow if you tell me what dv is and then the antiderivative, v?

Comment: Sunny.  You can find $dv$ by differentiating $v$.  I suspect that that is something you can do on your own?

Comment: Actually I am having a problem with how you calculated v. Did you use a certain formula for example: $\int\ tan\ (u)\ du= \ln\ |sec(u)|+ C$

Comment: Which $v$ Sunny?  There were $3$ IBP in the post.

Comment: If u was $xe^{2x}$ and $dv=\frac{1}{(1+2x)^2}$ How did you get v. Or did I start out with the wrong dv and if so how should I set up dv?

Comment: Integrate $1/(1+2x)^2$ to get $-1/(2(2x+1))$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the integral as presented by the proposer:
$\int\frac{xe^{2x}}{(1+2x)^2}dx$ with $u = 1 + 2x$. This leads to
\begin{align}
\int\frac{xe^{2x}}{(1+2x)^2}dx &= \frac{1}{2} \, \int \left(\frac{u-1}{2} \right) \, e^{u-1} \, \frac{du}{u^{2}} \\
&= \frac{1}{4e} \, \int \left( \frac{e^{u}}{u} - \frac{e^{u}}{u^{2}} \right) \, du \\
&= \frac{1}{4e} \, \left[ Ei(u) - \left( Ei(u) - \frac{e^{u}}{u} \right) \right] + c_{0} \\
&= \frac{e^{u-1}}{4 \, u} + c_{0} \\
&= \frac{e^{2x}}{4 \, (1+2x)} + c_{0}. 
\end{align}
Note that $Ei(x)$ is the Exponential integral.

This solution produces the same solution as that presented by Dr.MV

Comment: But you don't need $Ei(x)$ in this problem...

Comment: Interesting solution!